# Creating an Authentication Platform, POST between JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Okay, so this is a proof of concept project that I want to do. I have one page that is checking for the authentication status though some sort of POST response in JQuery. Here's that code:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    window.open('http://authorize.openauth.tk/','title', 'width=360, height=240');
        return false;
$.ajax({
type: POST,
url: "http://authorize.openauth.tk/",
success: function(data){
if(data == '1'){
    $('h1').fadeToggle(function(){
      $('#authStat').css('color', 'green').html("Authenticated!");
          $('h1').fadeToggle();
    });
  }
  else{
      $('h1').fadeToggle(function(){
      $('#authStat').css('color', 'red').html("Not authenticated.");
      $('h1').fadeToggle();
      });
  }}
  });
});
```

When I click Login, it opens the login window, and that it. In Firebug, I don't see a POST request to "authorize.openauth.tk". Now, I know that the above code is NOT doing what I described. What code should I use? My main goal: Click a button, open a connection to a page, open that page in a separate window, and then having the page in the window report back to the main page.
Here's the code for "the page in the window":

```
var referrer =  document.referrer;
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "auth.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == "0"){
            $('h1').html("Wrong Username/Password");
        }
    else{
        $.post(referrer, data);
    }
  }
});
alert(referrer);
});
```

Comment: And just ask if you want clarification.

Comment: You know `window.open()` is probably going to be prevented by nearly every popup blocker out there.

Comment: Like I said... Proof of concept. I just need to figure out how to pass the data around. I'm working on a solution now.